# 2d trilateration

Tags: artificial-intelligence, trilateration

I am writing some code to participate in an AI challenge. The main objective for the AI challenge is to take a simulated robot and navigate it through a maze to a destination zone. The secondary objective which is optional is to find a recharger placed in the maze at an unknown location. This is all done in a 2D grid.

My program can call a method to get a distance measurement from the recharger. So using trilateration I should be able to locate the recharger by calling this method, recording my ai's current position and the distance the recharger is away from that point 3 times over.

I found this example of trilateration on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration but this applies to a 3d space. I'm only dealing with a 2D space. Also I don't understand how to use the formula shown in Wikipedia, searching the web for a working example with numbers plugged in and boiling down to the final coordinates is scarce with Google searches.

I'm not a math major; I am just an enthusiast exploring AI problems.

An explanation and step by step example of how to calculate the problem is what I need as mathematics are not my strong point. Below is some sample data:

- Point 1: x=39, y=28, distance=8
- Point 2: x=13, y=39, distance=11
- Point 3: x=16, y=40, distance=8

Any example using my sample data would be greatly appreciated. The programming to this will be very straight forward once I can wrap my head around the mathematics.

Comment: Just take the 3D formulas and set height to zero.

Comment: That would definitely work, but I don't know how to use the formula on wikipedia. I'm looking for a step by step example of how to go through the calculations.

Comment: May I ask which AI challenge?

Comment: http://www2.mohawkcollege.ca/events/amazebot/ Mohawk College's amazebot challenge. It's a great academic project. It's purely optional, no grades will be given for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the Wikipedia trilateriation [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) describes, you compute (x,y) coordinates by successively calculating: e<sub>x</sub>, i, e<sub>y</sub>, d, j, x, y. You have to be familiar with vector notation, so, for example, e<sub>x</sub> = (P2 - P1) / ‖P2 - P1‖ means:

- e<sub>x,x</sub> = (P2<sub>x</sub> - P1<sub>x</sub>) / sqrt((P2<sub>x</sub> - P1<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (P2<sub>y</sub> - P1<sub>y</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)
- e<sub>x,y</sub> = (P2<sub>y</sub> - P1<sub>y</sub>) / sqrt((P2<sub>x</sub> - P1<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (P2<sub>y</sub> - P1<sub>y</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)

Your data is:

- P1 = (39, 28); r<sub>1</sub> = 8
- P2 = (13, 39); r<sub>2</sub> = 11
- P3 = (16, 40); r<sub>3</sub> = 8

The calculation steps are:

1. e<sub>x</sub> = (P2 - P1) / ‖P2 - P1‖
2. i = e<sub>x</sub>(P3 - P1)
3. e<sub>y</sub> = (P3 - P1 - i · e<sub>x</sub>) / ‖P3 - P1 - i · e<sub>x</sub>‖
4. d = ‖P2 - P1‖
5. j = e<sub>y</sub>(P3 - P1)
6. x = (r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> - r<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup>) / 2d
7. y = (r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> - r<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + i<sup>2</sup> + j<sup>2</sup>) / 2j - ix / j

Comment: perfect thank you. Now I can understand where these variables are coming from. I'll have to do some practice with vectors of course but this is a good start. Thank you Don :).

Comment: and the last step to get real coordinates of unknown point as tells Wiki are as follows: `8. p1,2 = P1 + x*ex + y*ey` gives the points in the original coordinate system since `ex` and `ey`, the basis unit vectors, are expressed in the original coordinate system. -- a comment from an edit from anonymous user

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400351/localizing-a-point-using-distances-to-three-other-points-in-3-d/23401529?noredirect=1#23401529 could you check this post too, please?

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı, too far away? It could mean that the input coordinates are bad. Collinear coordinates might do that, for example.

Comment: @DonReba I check collinearity. My points are `[-0.8092775327548827, -19.576297388406005, 0.0]`, `[0.8541381922861269, -9.975819993705937, 0.0]` and `[-0.597554605602997, -18.347159283433726, 0.0]`. `y = 13233.037425080443`.