# Trilateration (2D) algorithm implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, geolocation, artificial-intelligence, trilateration

I am trying to implement the Trilateration process in 2D. The wikipedia article relating to this: [Tilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration)

I have found a nice question here at this site, where the algorithm is well explained:[artifical intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747227/2d-trilateration)

After all, I tried to implement the algorithm in c++. Unfortunately I faced some problems...
Let's see my implementation. It is only a function: The first inputs are three vector, each representing a 2D point with X,Y coordinates. The other (r1,r2,r3) input variables stand for the distance/radius of each point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

std::vector<double> trilateration(double point1[], double point2[], double point3[], double r1, double r2, double r3) {
    std::vector<double> resultPose;
    //unit vector in a direction from point1 to point 2
    double p2p1Distance = pow(pow(point2[0]-point1[0],2) + pow(point2[1]-point1[1],2),0.5);
    double exx = (point2[0]-point1[0])/p2p1Distance;
    double exy = (point2[1]-point1[1])/p2p1Distance;
    //signed magnitude of the x component
    double ix = exx*(point3[0]-point1[0]);
    double iy = exy*(point3[1]-point1[1]);
    //the unit vector in the y direction. 
    double eyx = (point3[0]-point1[0]-ix*exx)/pow(pow(point3[0]-point1[0]-ix*exx,2) + pow(point3[1]-point1[1]-iy*exy,2),0.5);
    double eyy = (point3[1]-point1[1]-iy*exy)/pow(pow(point3[0]-point1[0]-ix*exx,2) + pow(point3[1]-point1[1]-iy*exy,2),0.5);
    //the signed magnitude of the y component
    double jx = eyx*(point3[0]-point1[0]);
    double jy = eyy*(point3[1]-point1[1]);
    //coordinates
    double x = (pow(r1,2) - pow(r2,2) + pow(p2p1Distance,2))/ (2 * p2p1Distance);
    double y = (pow(r1,2) - pow(r3,2) + pow(iy,2) + pow(jy,2))/2*jy - ix*x/jx;
    //result coordinates
    double finalX = point1[0]+ x*exx + y*eyx;
    double finalY = point1[1]+ x*exy + y*eyy;
    resultPose.push_back(finalX);
    resultPose.push_back(finalY);
    return resultPose;
}
```

As I mentioned I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747227/2d-trilateration) article. I am of the opinion that the problem lies at the part where the y coordinate is calculated. I am also not sure about last part, where I calculate finalX, finalY...

My main function is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::vector<double> finalPose;
    double p1[] = {4.0,4.0};
    double p2[] = {9.0,7.0};
    double p3[] = {9.0,1.0};
    double r1,r2,r3;
    r1 = 4;
    r2 = 3;
    r3 = 3.25;
    finalPose = trilateration(p1,p2,p3,r1,r2,r3);
    cout<<"X:::  "<<finalPose[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Y:::  "<<finalPose[1]<<endl; 
    //x = 8, y = 4.1

}
```

The result should be around X~8 and Y~4.1, but I got X = 13.5542 and Y=-5.09038

So my problem is and question is: I have problem with dividing the calculations for x and y. I think I could solve the algorithm till x, after that I have problems with calculating y.

The calculation is the following for y: y = (r12 - r32 + i2 + j2) / 2j - ix / j

I do not know which i and j  I should use here since I have two i (ix,iy) and two j(jx,jy). As you can see I used iy and jy but at the end of the line I used ix due to multiplication with x.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Could someone please help me?"_ Did you actually state a concrete problem (besides linking) or question besides this?

Comment: You absolutely got the point, sorry for this. I edit my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear, and perhaps incorrect, in the [linked SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747227/2d-trilateration) that the values of `i` and `j` are scalar values and computed a bit differently than the other vector quantities. More explicitly you should have:

i = e<sub>x</sub> · (P3 - P1) = e<sub>xx</sub> (P3<sub>x</sub> - P1<sub>x</sub>) + e<sub>xy</sub> (P3<sub>y</sub> - P1<sub>y</sub>) = ix + iy

j = e<sub>y</sub> · (P3 - P1) = e<sub>yx</sub> (P3<sub>x</sub> - P1<sub>x</sub>) + e<sub>yy</sub> (P3<sub>y</sub> - P1<sub>y</sub>) = jx + jy

Note that `·` is the dot product of two vectors here. Thus, in your code there should be no `ix`, `iy`, `jx` or `jy`.

Also, in your calculation of `y` you should change the denominator of `/2*j` to:

```
 / (2*j)
```

otherwise you are multiplying by `j` instead of dividing. Making these changes gives me the result of `[7.05, 5.74]` which is closer to your expected values.

Comment: waohh, you are a genius! I appreciate you help, it works! For me i got the right coordinates (8.02,4.13)

Comment: I would like to ask an additional question, if no problem. If I want to expand it to the 3D case, where spheres intersect each other, the only thing I should add is: z = ±sqrt(r12 - x2 - y2)? The following question is about it: http://goo.gl/y30gPn . What is your advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the 3D case it looks like you would just need to add a z component to each of the vectors (`exz`, `eyz`) and compute `ez` and `z` as on the Wikipedia page. Then the calculation for the final coordinates would add the term `±z * ez` where `ez` is a vector (so you would need `ezx`, `ezy` and `ezz` like the other terms).

Comment: Thanks! As i see the "ez" can be calculated with the cross product of ex and ey. I tried to do this, what do you think it is good? "ezx=exx*eyx", "ezy=exy*eyy", "ezz=exz*eyz" . After these steps the final Z coordinate should be: point1[2] + x * exz + y * eyz + z * ezz (where z = ±sqrt(r12 - x2 - y2)) Am I right? By the way i am really grateful, I like this site and helpful people like you very much!

Comment: Because to the best of my knowledge, if we want to get a 3D coordinates, we should have 4 sphere for the clear and unequivocal solution. But I have really no clue where to put the data of the 4th point to this equations...Do you know how to handle the data of the 4th point/sphere?

Comment: The Wikipedia article only mentions 3 spheres (Trilateration, Tri = 3) and says there can be 0, 1 or 2 solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I used a couple of auxiliary variables but it works just fine...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct point 
{
    float x,y;
};

float norm (point p) // get the norm of a vector
{
    return pow(pow(p.x,2)+pow(p.y,2),.5);
}

point trilateration(point point1, point point2, point point3, double r1, double r2, double r3) {
    point resultPose;
    //unit vector in a direction from point1 to point 2
    double p2p1Distance = pow(pow(point2.x-point1.x,2) + pow(point2.y-   point1.y,2),0.5);
    point ex = {(point2.x-point1.x)/p2p1Distance, (point2.y-point1.y)/p2p1Distance};
    point aux = {point3.x-point1.x,point3.y-point1.y};
    //signed magnitude of the x component
    double i = ex.x * aux.x + ex.y * aux.y;
    //the unit vector in the y direction. 
    point aux2 = { point3.x-point1.x-i*ex.x, point3.y-point1.y-i*ex.y};
    point ey = { aux2.x / norm (aux2), aux2.y / norm (aux2) };
    //the signed magnitude of the y component
    double j = ey.x * aux.x + ey.y * aux.y;
    //coordinates
    double x = (pow(r1,2) - pow(r2,2) + pow(p2p1Distance,2))/ (2 * p2p1Distance);
    double y = (pow(r1,2) - pow(r3,2) + pow(i,2) + pow(j,2))/(2*j) - i*x/j;
    //result coordinates
    double finalX = point1.x+ x*ex.x + y*ey.x;
    double finalY = point1.y+ x*ex.y + y*ey.y;
    resultPose.x = finalX;
    resultPose.y = finalY;
    return resultPose;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    point finalPose;
    point p1 = {4.0,4.0};
    point p2 = {9.0,7.0};
    point p3 = {9.0,1.0};
    double r1,r2,r3;
    r1 = 4;
    r2 = 3;
    r3 = 3.25;
    finalPose = trilateration(p1,p2,p3,r1,r2,r3);
    cout<<"X:::  "<<finalPose.x<<endl;
    cout<<"Y:::  "<<finalPose.y<<endl; 
}
```

$ the output is:

```
X:::  8.02188
Y:::  4.13021
```