# Trilateration Issue

Tags: math, trilateration

As I know that Trilateration is the process of finding the center of the area of intersection of three spheres. I wrote Trilateration method in c++, I took the equations and it is details from [Trilaterationenter in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) and [2d trilateration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747227/2d-trilateration?answertab=active#tab-top)

When take an example like the following:

**Example_1:** p1(5,10), p2(15,10), p3(10,20), and r1 = 9, r2 = 7, r3 = 8, the answer is (11.6, 13.8)  which is logical answer.

[image]

but when case like the following  example, the answer is like  a garbage number, I made sure from the calculations but in such case I don't know the reason!

**Example_2:** p1(53.279999, 67.040001) , p2(45.860001, 57.330002) , p3( 66.370003, 84.169998) , and r1= 5.824241 , r2 = 8.522444 , r3= 28.456253 , the answer is (910813 ,-695906)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trilateration works for three non-collinear points. Your points look almost collinear, so some denominator in expressions (I cannot see you code :)) has very small value, and solution is absolutely inexact huge-coordinate point.

Comment: No, they are non col linear (they don't lie in the same line) even they are showing that.

Comment: Yes, there is a very small value which is when calculate y in this equation: y = (r12 - r32 + i2 + j2) / 2j - ix / j

Comment: But in this case, why it can't estimate the center of the common area!! and how we can calculate intersection point in such cases?!

Comment: because this method is intended for above good case, not for degenerate bottom one. Small value causes very big numerical errors, so another approach is needed here.

Comment: Thanks @MBo, but any idea if there is a technique to determine if the points are good or degenerate before using trailteration?

Comment: To find if points are degenerate - calculate triangle area through crossproduct and normalize it dividing by squared longest triangle edge. Small value - degenerate case

Comment: I have similar problem. but with java.